# The Easiest Impossible Sort - PowerBI

Tags: sorting, powerbi, pivot

Hate to be  dramatic with the title to the question - but I'm telling you - I have exhausted MANY avenues on this what seems like it should be the easiest thing on earth.  I have flipped the orientation of a Matrix table so my rows are each a separate variable.  For example, in survey data, each row is a frustration expierenced by the customer and the cells are averages of frequency of this frustration and my column headers are different values of a SINGLE field, call it Provider -

```
            Company 1 | Company 2 | Company .. n
```

Frust_1

Frust_2

....

Frust_n

Is everyone picking up what I'm putting down?  Sorting the values down this columns is IMPOSSIBLE in Power BI.  Because it's recognizing 66 different variables, not 1 variable to sort.  But I mean - THIS IS SO EASY!!! Why can't it be done by clicking an arrow still?  They have to be able to push this as an update that would have to help many people.

Any ideas?  I've tried C# solutions in Tabular Editor, and I have tried aggregating the 66 factors but that's not working .... If anyone has any ideas, please respond!

Comment: Matrix visual is very similar to a Pivot Table in Excel. You cannot sort individual columns in a Matrix, unless you have separate values in the Values well and without any columns in Columns well.